# Nested php functions not calling the second function

Tags: php, sql, function

The code below is a rather complicated function (`display_analysis();`) with another function inside (`analysis_column();`) with multiple variables. I confess my ignorance why this should or should not work. I know there are many variables that could cause problems and nested php functions is not ideal, however I just need some advice about the current problem, that is the `analysis_column();` functions not working.

The first function `display_analyses();`:

```
function display_analyses($analysis_type) {

    require 'dbh.php';
    global $order_id;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM analysis_database JOIN microbiology_analysis_database ON analysis_database.m_analysis_id=microbiology_analysis_database.id WHERE order_id=$order_id AND analysis_database.analysis_type='$analysis_type';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $analysis_prepared = '';
    $prepared_by = '';

    $step_1 = '';
    $step_2 = '';
    $step_3 = '';
    $step_4 = '';
    $step_5 = '';
    $step_6 = '';
    $step_7 = '';
    $step_8 = '';
    $step_9 = '';

    $output = '';
    $output .= '
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th width="10%">Analysis</th>
    <th width="20%">Step 1</th>
    <th width="20%">Step 2</th>
    <th width="20%">Step 3</th>
    <th width="20%">Step 4</th>
    <th width="20%">Final Step</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output .= 
        '<tr>
        <td>
        <input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id" id="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row['analysis_id'].'" readonly>
        <input class="hidden" name="order_id" id="order_id" value="'.$row['order_id'].'" readonly></td>


        <td>'.$row['analysis_name'].'</td>';

        analysis_column(1);
        analysis_column(2);
        analysis_column(3);
        analysis_column(4);

        if ($row['step_10'] == '') {
            $output .= '<td></td>';
        } elseif ($row['step_10_progress'] == 'Completed') {
            $analyst_single = $row['step_10_analyst'];
            $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM employee_database WHERE id=$analyst_single";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
            $input3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
            $output .= '<td style="color:green;"><form class="analysis_progress">
            <input class="hidden analysis_number" name="analysis_number" value="10">
            <input class="hidden analysis_id" name="analysis_id" value="'.$row['analysis_id'].'" readonly>
            <input title="Analyst: '.$input3['first_name'].' '.$input3['last_name'].' ('.$row['step_10_date'].' | '.$row['step_10_time'].')" name="step_number" class="step_10 analysis_progress_check" type="checkbox" checked disabled>'.$row['step_10'].'<br><em>'.$input3['first_name'].' '.$input3['last_name'].'</em></form></td>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<td><form class="analysis_progress">
            <input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row['m_analysis_id'].'">
            <input class="hidden analysis_number" name="analysis_number" value="10">
            <input class="hidden analysis_id" name="analysis_id" value="'.$row['analysis_id'].'" readonly>
            <input title="Analysis Pending" name="step_number" class="step_10 analysis_progress_check" type="checkbox">'.$row['step_10'].'</form></td>';
        } 
    }
    $output .= '</tbody>';

    echo $output;

}
```

And the second function `analysis_column();`:

```
function analysis_column($number) {

    require 'dbh.php';
    global $output; 
    global $row;
    global $order_id;

    if ($row['step_'.$number] == '') {
        $output .= '<td></td>';
    } elseif ($row['step_'.$number.'_progress'] == 'Completed') {
        $analyst_single = $row['step_'.$number.'_analyst'];
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM employee_database WHERE id=$analyst_single";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        $input3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
        $output .= '<td style="color:green;"><form>
        <input class="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'">
        <input class="hidden analysis_number" name="this_analysis_number" value="'.$number.'">
        <input class="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'">
        <input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row['m_analysis_id'].'">
        <input class="hidden analysis_id" name="analysis_id" value="'.$row['analysis_id'].'" readonly>
        <input name="step_number" class="step_'.$number.' analysis_progress_check" type="checkbox" checked disabled>'.$row['step_'.$number].'<br><em>'.$input3['first_name'].' '.$input3['last_name'].'</em> | <i class="completed_analysis_link fas fa-info"></form></i></td>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<td><form id="analysis_form" class="analysis_progress">
        <input class="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'">
        <input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row['m_analysis_id'].'">
        <input class="hidden analysis_number" name="analysis_number" value="'.$number.'">
        <input class="hidden analysis_id" name="analysis_id" value="'.$row['analysis_id'].'" readonly>
        <input title="Analysis Pending" name="step_number" class="step_'.$number.' analysis_progress_check" type="checkbox">'.$row['step_'.$number].'';

        if ($row['step_'.$number.'_duration'] != '') {
            $output .= '
            <input class="hidden" name="duration_'.$number.'" value="'.$row['step_'.$number.'_duration'].'" readonly>
            <input title="Step Duration" value="Step duration: '.$row['step_'.$number.'_duration'].' (hh:mm)" placeholder="Step duration: '.$row['step_'.$number.'_duration'].' (hh:mm)" readonly>';

        } if ($row['step_'.$number.'_date_prev'] == 'Yes') {
            $output .= '<input title="Enter an additional date to the step" name="date_prev_'.$number.'" type="date" value="">';
        } if ($row['step_'.$number.'_storage'] == 'Yes') {

            $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM storage_database WHERE storage_type='cold_store';";
            $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);

            $output .= '
            <input title="Select a storage location for this step" name="storage_location_'.$number.'" placeholder="Select a Storage Location" list="storage_location_list">
            <datalist id="storage_location_list">';
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
                $output .= '<option>'.$row2['storage_name'].' <em>('.$row2['storage_temp'].' &#8451)</em></option>';
            }
            $output .= '</datalist>';

        } if ($row['step_'.$number.'_incubation'] == 'Yes') {

            $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM storage_database WHERE storage_type='incubator';";
            $result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);

            $output .= '
            <input title="Select a incubator for this step" name="incubation_'.$number.'" placeholder="Select a Incubator" list="incubation_list">
            <datalist id="incubation_list">';
            while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)) {
                $output .= '<option>'.$row3['storage_name'].' <em>('.$row3['storage_temp'].' &#8451)</em>';
            }
            $output .= '</datalist>';

        } if ($row['step_'.$number.'_input'] == 'Yes') {
            $output .= '<input title="Input some additional step information..." name="ex_input_'.$number.'" placeholder="Input some additional step information..." value="">';
        }
        $output .= '</form></td>';
    }
}
```

This is where the functions are initially called:

```
if (isset($_GET['display_analyses'])) {
    $order_id = $_GET['display_analyses'];

    if ($_GET['analysis_type'] == 'Microbiological') {
        display_analyses('Microbiological');
    } elseif ($_GET['analysis_type'] == 'Chemical') {
        display_analyses('Chemical');
    } 
}
```

Again, I am aware my php scripting methodology needs work and I should used prepared statements, although I only require a solution to the functions problem.

Comment: What is the meaning of "not working"?

Comment: There is a empty result.

Comment: I would assume this condition is satisfied then: `$row['step_'.$number] == ''`

Comment: Yes I tested both functions individually and they work. Only when they are nested does the second function not work.